# Adding non active constraints to existing UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, nslayoutconstraint

I have `UIView` for which I have set constraints in IB. Now in code, i want to do some animation, by adding some new constraints and deactivating old. First I add new constraint to view, that is inactive, like this:

```
// camera view new constraints
    self.cameraNewLeftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.cameraView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:self.smallImageContainerView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                               multiplier:1.0
                                                                 constant:0];
    self.cameraNewLeftConstraint.active = NO;
    [self.presentationView addConstraint:self.cameraNewLeftConstraint];
```

But this generates constraint warning during runtime (stnadard message - will attempt to break some constraints), that I have conflicting constraints, although I have added inactive constraint. How can I deal with this, how is this supposed to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views don't have inactive constraints.  If you add a constraint to a view, then that constraint will be active.

The new method of setting the `active` property to `YES` adds the constraint to the proper view for you.  In your code, when you called `addConstraint`, iOS added your constraint to your view, and changed `active` to `YES`.

So, don't call `addConstraint` on the view.  Just create the constraint and set its `active` property to `YES` when you want it to be used.

Comment: Is this something that existed from start, or was added later, like iOS9...?

Comment: The `active` property was added in iOS8.  It is a much better way of doing things because you don't have to figure out which views to add the constraints to.  iOS can figure that out from the `item` and `toItem`.

Comment: If you have a bunch of constraints in an array (called `myArrayOfContraints)` you want to activate at once, you can use the class method `[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints: myArrayOfContraints]`.